# deleting part after a specific character and that character

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm working within my command line/bash on a large file with millions of rows. I'm analyzing the data with a software that requires the rsIDs to be less than 40 characters.

> ```
> awk 'length($2)>40' 1000G_All_chr_merged.bim > IDtoolong.bim
> head IDtoolong.bim 
> 1 rs540674385;rs540674385;rs540674385;rs576523156 0   4439107 AAG AAGGAGG
> 1 rs561687032;rs546685337;rs528205989;rs370782231 0   4804685 GCACACA GCA
> 1 rs561021122;rs542858700;rs527502051;rs560257256;rs545143128 0   6210427 AGG GGAAT
> 1 rs529037702;rs561824298;rs539915961;rs528175459 0   12122415    CCCATCCAT   AT
> 1 rs571308260;rs549871057;rs537509991;rs587738155 0   12611561    CAAA    CAAAA
> 1 rs553093917;rs553093917;rs534535365;rs570185860 0   16657917    AAAT    AAATAAT
> ```

How can I run through the second column and delete the first semicolon, ;, and anything after that?

I tried this:

> `awk '{sub(/;.*/,"", $2)}' 1000G_All_chr_merged.bim > adjusted_IDlength.bim`

And I also using sed but found myself ruining the file at one point. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that by "ruining the file" you mean changing the white space between fields. If that's the problem, the following won't do that:

```
$ sed 's/;[^[:space:]]*//' file
1 rs540674385 0   4439107 AAG AAGGAGG
1 rs561687032 0   4804685 GCACACA GCA
1 rs561021122 0   6210427 AGG GGAAT
1 rs529037702 0   12122415    CCCATCCAT   AT
1 rs571308260 0   12611561    CAAA    CAAAA
1 rs553093917 0   16657917    AAAT    AAATAAT
```